# Why doesn't PHP's get_meta_tags work on some URL's?

Tags: php, meta-tags

Why does the code below work great on most websites (such as www.apple.com), but doesn't work for others (such as www.yahoo.com)?

```
$tags = get_meta_tags( $webpage );

if( $tags )
{
    if( $tags['description'] )
    {
        $link_description = $tags['description'];
    }
    else
    {
        $link_description = '';
    }
}
```

When I say that it doesn't work, what I mean is that the script just stalls. My program is left hanging. Is there a way to catch when get_meta_tags() doesn't work and handle this with an alternative block of code? I thought I was doing this when I wrote

```
$tags = get_meta_tags( $webpage );

if( $tags )
{
    // stuff
}
else
{
    // handle the case when the above doesn't work.
}
```

However, it still stalls on sites like www.yahoo.com. Any ideas on how to handle these troublesome URL's?

Comment: Do you use http:// in front of it?

Comment: yes. It works fine for most sites, but never works for others. There must be some problem with the data retrieved from the meta tags from those sites that breaks the script.

Comment: Update: I found that by sanitizing the data everything works. That is, I did this: `real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($tags['description']))`.